# Rails with Bootstrap (on Windows) - empty application.css file and styling won't load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-5, twitter-bootstrap-rails

[image]

Relevant part of GemFile:
[image]

Bundle install: 
[image]

*And still no effect:* 
[image]

From \app\views\layouts\application.html.erb:

```html
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

application.js:

```js
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

How do I load Bootstrap styling?

Comment: May I know what all files are there in your app/assets/stylesheets folder?

Answer (score 0):

Seems youre missing to import bootstrap styles. To solve this according to the `bootstrap-sass` [documentation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails) you should:

Import Bootstrap styles in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

```
// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

bootstrap-sprockets must be imported before bootstrap for the icon fonts to work.

Make sure the file has .scss extension (or .sass for Sass syntax). If you have just generated a new Rails app, it may come with a .css file instead

Answer (score 0):

First you should decide which gem to use, `twitter-bootstrap-rails` or `bootstrap-sass`, not both.

Let's say you use `bootstrap-sass` then in your `application.js` should be

`//= require bootstrap-sprockets`

not

`//= require twitter/bootstrap`

and then add

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

to your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` like [R. Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7654691/r-sierra) said.

Now your app should be good to go!